# Variance and standard deviation for wrapped distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

According to Wiki-article about the wrapped normal distribution, the definitions of **standard deviation** for a given wrapped distribution is
$$s = \sqrt{\ln\frac{1}{R^2}},\quad R=|\langle z\rangle|,$$
where $z=e^{i\theta}$ and $\theta\in [0,2\pi]$ is the angular variable,
$$\langle z\rangle = \oint_{\Gamma}dz\,zf(z),$$
where $f=f(z)$ is the wrapped distribution and $\Gamma$ is the contour of lenght $2\pi$. As Is understand from Wiki-article about wrapped Cauchy distribution and von Mises distribution, the **variance** of wrapped distribution is defined by
$$\sigma=1-R.$$
Naively, I keep in mind that $s=\sqrt{\sigma}$. As was mentioned in comments, in directional statistics $s$ and $\sigma$ are different quantities.

**Question:** why the standard deviation for wrapped distribution is defined in such way?

Comment: Another [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_statistics#Dispersion) suggests the "circular standard deviation"   is not the square root of the "circular variance"

Comment: @Henry thx, I have missed this. I have edited the question